# How can I exclude part of my profile depending on 32bit or 64bit version of PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

How can I exclude part of my profile depending on 32bit or 64bit version of PowerShell

If I have the following ...

```
Function BTS: {Set-Location BTS:} 
Function BTS:\ {Set-Location BTS:} 

$InitializeDefaultBTSDrive = $false
Add-PSSnapIn BizTalkFactory.PowerShell.Extensions
New-PSDrive -Name BTS -PSProvider BizTalk -Root BTS:\ `
            -Instance . -Database BizTalkMgmtDb
```

in my profile ...

> ..\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

then it works fine if I run the x86 PowerShell, but I get an error with the x64 ... *which is expected as the snapin is only meant to be run in x86*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
if ([System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess) {
    # code for 64-bit
}
else {
    # code for 32-bit
}
```